# Typescript create type from array of months

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to generate a new type from an array in Typescript?

I have a list of months in a variable, is there a way to generate a new type as `MonthName: MonthNumber`

For example:

```
const Months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
] as const;
```

The output should be:

```
type MonthsWithNumber = {
'January': 01,
'February': 02,
'March': 03,
'April': 04,
'May': 05,
'June': 06,
'July': 07,
'August': 08,
'September': 09,
'October': 10,
'November': 11,
'December': 12
}
```

Comment: I find your question unclear, could you please articulate more so that you can get some help? What's your final goal? How have you approached the problem?

Comment: `02` is not allowed format of number

Answer (score 1):

> In the answer below, I've renamed your `Months` array to `monthNames`.

The first step is getting a union of the string literals in your array. Let's call it `MonthName`:

```ts
type MonthName = typeof monthNames[number];
```

After that, creating the type is pretty easy: you can use the type utility [`Record<MonthName, number>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to create an object-like type representing month names as property keys and their corresponding numbers as values. Creating the data structure isn't too difficult either, although it requires using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). That looks like this:

```ts
const monthNumberMap = Object.fromEntries(
  monthNames.map((name, i) => [name, i + 1])
) as Record<MonthName, number>;
```

Putting it all together:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=20&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtuKALAcgQzgUwjAvDAbQCgYYByAKTTAFc0AnATzIBoTyAxTAI3rqdbsyAWQbAkg0mQCCAB3oBLADaTyo5mykUaYTKso0lGodJoBzGtH0BlTLKiY43TPX0B5YFBDPXm8ihAAN0cffQARTGAQl0EAXRg0HFBIKABuIiIoRllMGGFEVAxc-CyckAAzeAL0LAgCWicXWPSiZOgqsGQUGkb6UVk8GDduACtIqAA6cvoQOABRTsVsAAp2BE7C2om4NFll5bAilhgFAEo8AD5CQ6xjhRgAahgARljTonPEmAAlSJB6AAmAB58hsaphjg0fBcWusuj0fP0JrZ7NF6OxSJisaQAPQ4gB6AH4Mm0QEpMBMlCAzMs4agES5+qdUjAcQAqGAAGRAIAA1jglApeZgAFxEADe7AARFRaAxGFKRS8-FKuLx+AqlQAmFWiejiRUwADMKrkiiUhoALLq0JqYABWFXaXSGgBsTsMdoA7KbzJYoIaABwqlEOXqGgCcKo8Xh8hueAAYVQFguGlc9niqIlE0y8tUQAL4wNk4ohAA)

```ts
const monthNames = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
] as const;

type MonthName = typeof monthNames[number];

const monthNumberMap = Object.fromEntries(
  monthNames.map((name, i) => [name, i + 1])
) as Record<MonthName, number>;

monthNumberMap.September
             //^? (property) September: number

console.log(monthNumberMap); /* Looks like:
{
  "January": 1,
  "February": 2,
  "March": 3,
  "April": 4,
  "May": 5,
  "June": 6,
  "July": 7,
  "August": 8,
  "September": 9,
  "October": 10,
  "November": 11,
  "December": 12
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
      type monthType = {
           [key in typeof Months[number]]: number;
      };
```